# Unable to post serilizable object from $http to web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, ajax, serialization, asp.net-web-api

web api has `[Serilizable]` model objects as that needs for serilization intense.
Now, when I post that model object from `$.http` call using below code then, it post without error but, no data populate and all values are null posted on web api.
If I remove `[Serilizable]` attribute then works fine and able to get all posted value.

```
return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: config.APIURL + 'Parts',
                data: JSON.stringify(part), // Strinify your object
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
```

web api POST method taking parameter as below object:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Part
    {
        public double? PartLength { get; set; }
    }
```

Please help me here.

Comment: What does your part object contain?

Comment: Just edited with object structure. If I remove `serilizable` attribute then works all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution finally. Need to mark the object with `[JsonObject]`,`[JsonProperty]` attributes as below.

```
 [Serializable]
    [JsonObject]
    public class SNPart
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public double? PartLength { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
```

thanks
dhaval